# Solution to differential difference equation

Tags: differential-equations, difference-equations

I'm interested in finding the general solution $f(x)$ of the equation: $(1+x)f'(x)+(f(x/2)-f(x))=-1$, $x\ge0$. Can Mathematica help here? For instance, it is easy to verify that the (slightly different) equation $(1+x)f'(x)+2(f(x/2)-f(x))=-1$ is solved by $f(x)=C-x$ where $C$ is an arbitrary constant. Can Mathematica help reach this conclusion?

Comment: Did you check [`RSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RSolve.html)?

Comment: Yes, to no avail. It doesn't seem to understand derivatives.

Comment: I had no luck with either `DSolve` or `NDSolve`. `DSolve[(1 + x) f'[x] + f[x/2] - f[x] == -1, f, x]` gave `DSolve::litarg` error.  `NDSolve[{(1 + x) f'[x] + f[x/2] - f[x] == -1, f[0] == 1}, f, {x, 0, 1}]` gave `NDSolve::cdelay` error, saying "the method currently implemented for delay differential equations does not support delays that depend directly on the time variable or dependent variables."

Comment: @ChrisK: I had exactly the same issues.

Answer (score 7):

A small number of Taylor coefficients in $x=0$ is enough for `FindSequenceFunction` to provide the whole Taylor series:

```
n = 10;
res = First[# /. Solve[Thread[Table[SeriesCoefficient[(1 + x) f'[x] + f[x/2] - f[x],
        {x, 0, i}], {i, 0, n}] == Table[SeriesCoefficient[-1, {x, 0, i}], {i, 0, n}]],
            #] &[Table[Derivative[i + 1][f][0], {i, 0, n}]]]
Sum[x^i/i! FindSequenceFunction[res, i], {i, 0, m}] + C[1]
```

> $C[1] + \sum _{i=0}^m -\frac{x^i \prod _{K[1]=1}^{i-1} -2^{-K[1]} \left(2^{K[1]} K[1]-2^{K[1]}+1\right)}{i!}$

If  `f` is replaced by this series in the equation, it is not hard to see that summing up to some `m` yields something with the form $c\ x^m$. (First include in each of the sums only the 1 or 2 terms that adds some $x^{m-1}$ and expand to see that $x^{m-1}$ disappears, hence after summing the first $m$ terms, there is only $c\ x^m$ that can have a non-zero coefficient). Now sum to $m$, discard all but the $x^m$ terms and simplify to see that $|c\ x^m|$ equals
$$|x|^m\prod _{K[1]=1}^m \frac{2^{-K[1]} \left(2^{K[1]} K[1]-2^{K[1]}+1\right)}{K[1]}$$

The factors in the product are all less than one, so the error of the Taylor series decrease to $0$ as $m\to \infty$ if (and probably only if) $|x|\leq 1$.